# DFA for binary numbers that have a remainder of 1 when divided by 3

Tags: dfa

I need a DFA for a set of all strings beginning with a 1 that, interpreted as the binary representation of an integer, have a remainder of 1 when divided by 3.

For example, the binary number 1010 b is decimal 10. When you divide 10 by 3 you get a remainder of 1, so 1010 is in the language. However, the binary number 1111 b is decimal 15. When you divide 15 by 3 you get a remainder of 0, so 1111 is not in the language.

I've attached my DFA below. Could you please check it?

[image: My DFA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct to me.

You could make two simplifications:

1. *q<sub>4</sub>* represents (mod 0), so you could make it the starting state and get rid of *q<sub>0</sub>* and *q<sub>5</sub>*. (Unless you are required to reject strings beginning with a 0? Your question doesn't specify.)
2. *q<sub>1</sub>* and *q<sub>3</sub>* can be merged. They both represent (mod 1) and have the same transitions.

These two changes would leave you with exactly 3 states, one for each remainder.